# On a Cauchy problem exercise.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I can't seem to find the trick to solve the following Cauchy problem:

\begin{cases} y' = \alpha( 1 - y/ \beta) y \\ y(0) = y_o  \end{cases}

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are greater than zero.

Anyone mind lending a hand?

Comment: One thing that should work is partial fractions.

Comment: Use the change of unknown function $z=\frac{1}{y}$.

Comment: This is a Riccati type equation. Look up the methods used to solve this. Also notice that $y=0$ and $y=\beta$ are trivial solutions to the ODE.

Comment: This is the logistic equation. Solution by partial fractions is immediate as suggested by  @André Nicolas.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $y=0$ and $y=\beta$ are trivial solutions.

The given equation is a Riccati type differential eqaution. If you have a solution $y_0$ to the equation you can construct the general solution using this Ansatz:

$$y=y_0+\frac{1}{u}=\beta+\frac{1}{u}$$

Plugging this into the equation will result in

$$u'=(2\beta-\alpha)u+\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$$

Solve this linear ODE and plug this back into 
$$y=\beta+\frac{1}{u}$$

to get the general solution.

Comment: $\beta$ is not necessary equal to $y_0$

Comment: @Mihail: could you give more details :)?

Comment: I understood that one of your claims is that $y=\beta $ is one of the solutions. But it may not satisfy the initial value condition.

Comment: You are right. But i think this still leads to a reasonable solution